# wrapper classes do not need constructor call?

Tags: java, constructor

Wrapper classes are like any other class right?
And to create an object we need to use the new keyword followed by the constructor call in Java. So why don't we need the new keyword and constructor call in case of wrapper class objects?

```
Integer j=50; // an object of Integer is created with value 50 but there is no need of new keyword!
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: Wrapper classes are not exactly your "regular classes". They differ from "other classes" in that the compiler provides special support for dealing with them. One of the things the compiler does is autoboxing: it converts primitive literals into wrappers without requiring a call of `new` or `valueOf`.

Comment: There are all kinds of classes of which you can obtain instances without explicitly using the `new` keyword or directly invoking a constructor.  Look at the various `String.valueOf()` methods, for example.  The wrapper classes and autoboxing are a bit special, to be sure, but you seem to be starting from a more generally faulty assumption.

Answer (score 0):

In the given case, autoboxing will be done by the compiler and that's why we don't need to use 'new' keyword.

Comment: It's _deprecated_ since 9 (in 2017, just before the Q was asked), but still _supported_ as of 18 (in 2022).